# How do I send javascript https post or webhook from static html web page form?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, azure, hugo

I have a static HTML web page with a form. When the form is filled out, I'd like the submit button to send an http post to a webhook somewhere else for processing.

The back story to this is that I have Hugo website, which is all static html pages. One of the pages has a form on it. If someone fills out that form and clicks on the submit button, I'd like that data to be sent to an Azure Function, Azure Runbook, etc via webhook I have set up to process the form data.

Is this kind of thing possible?

Note that the Hugo website is hosted on storage where PHP or any server side processing and such is not available. This is why I'm looking for another way. My only idea was client-side javascript, if possible, but I am not so great with Javascript.

This is what I have so far, if it's even possible, but the webhook is never received. So something isn't right, or not what I think and isn't doable:

```
<script>
function sendWebhook() {
    var content = {"value1" : "test data"};
    var url = "https://s16events.azure-automation.net/webhooks?token=<myToken>";
    var options =  {
    "method" : "post",
    "contentType" : "application/json",
    "payload" : JSON.stringify(content)
};
return UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
}
</script>
<input id="contact-submit" type="button" class="btn btn-transparent" value="Submit" onclick="sendWebhook()" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call a webhook from a static html via js , I am afraid it is impossible for now as Azure automation webhook not supports CORS at present. See [user voice here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/246290-automation/suggestions/15318723-cors-support-for-azure-automation-webhooks) .

But you can call Azure Function from a static html with [CORS configed](https://github.com/uglide/azure-content/blob/master/articles/app-service-api/app-service-api-cors-consume-javascript.md).
This is my http trigged function code using c#  :

```
#r "Newtonsoft.Json"

using System.Net;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
{
    log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

    string value1 = req.Query["value1"];

    string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
    dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
    value1 = value1 ?? data?.value1;

    return value1 != null
        ? (ActionResult)new OkObjectResult($"Hello, {value1}")
        : new BadRequestObjectResult("Please pass a value1 on the query string or in the request body");
}
```

It will reply you with the value of "value1" in your html.

This is the code for html :

```
<script>
function sendWebhook() {

    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = '<URL OF YOUR AZURE FUNCTION>';
    var content = {"value1" : "test data"};
    http.open('POST', url, true);

    //Send the proper header information along with the request
    http.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');

    http.onreadystatechange = function() {//Call a function when the state changes.
        if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
            alert(http.responseText);
        }
    }
    http.send(JSON.stringify(content));

}
</script>


<input id="contact-submit" type="button" class="btn btn-transparent" value="Submit" onclick="sendWebhook()" />
```

Let's go to your Azure function =>Platform features=>CORS to enbale all Origins with "*" so that we can test locally : 
[image]

Test Result :

[image]

As you can see, your value1 data has been posted .